# In Bluetooth Master-Slave architecture can a Slave initiate the connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My company makes industrial products where Android devices talk to a PC to control an industrial process.   Currently they use WiFi but we want to replace that with Bluetooth for some applications.   I'm a Bluetooth newbie and I'm trying to learn the basics.  I'll be programming the Android side.

My understanding is that Bluetooth uses a master-slave architecture, where 1 master can support up to 7 slaves.    But I've read elsewhere on the web that the master has to initiate the connection. Is this true?   We would prefer to initiate the connection on the Android side.

Furthermore, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066889/how-to-programatically-determine-bluetooth-master-slave-roles) makes it seem like the master/slave status is not even accessible programmatically . . .

> "The master/slave roles which a device assumes is invisible to the
>   user(application)."

Is that true, because if it is then how does either side even know if it CAN initiate a connection?

If it matters, the intention is to send blocks of binary data in both directions over the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, You can change the master/slave roles during connection. Probably not accessible from android API level.

Master is controlling pretty low-level parameters like clock. On the high level, when for example using BT RFCOMM, it has absolutely no meaning.
As for max number of connections, this might be hardware specific additionally to any spec imposed constraints.